# Finding an infinite (or very large) loop in JavaScript using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using a third party statistics library which seems to have loads of issues. It's both large and compressed, so it's not particularly easy to debug. I'm using the Chrome Dev Tools and I was wondering what options there might be for ranking functions by the number of calls by their name, maybe? I thought the answer was the Profiler tab, but the profiles I captured are only documenting the JS files referencing "line 1" in long chains.

This thing is freezing my app and I'd rather avoid making changes to their code as much as possible, even if its for the sake of debugging.  I'm happy to clarify anything that's not clear.

EDIT:  I seem to remember a recent demo of chrome dev tools somewhere showing a timeline that depicted function blocks stacked vertically based on the time increment going horizontally called "flame charts" or something similar... That would be ideal, but I can't remember the link right now for the life of me.  Not opposed to using Canary on this one at all if anyone knows what this tool is?

Comment: I suspect you're going to need un-minified code to do this properly. All the tools I know give you performance by line number.

Comment: I tried "pretty printing" the library before profiling, but it didn't seem to work.  I may just resort to doing it in the IDE, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Have you tried http://jsbeautifier.org/ ?

Comment: Yes I have, great tool.  There's also a button in chrome dev tools with a "{}" symbol that will pretty print the javascript for you, which is amazing!  Apparently it doesn't impact the profiler references though.  It's more the back and forth of it all that I'm trying to avoid.  I've got an answer coming soon, just taking some screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest video about DevTools is here http://youtu.be/x6qe_kVaBpg?t=19m44s

It covers different topics about DevTools and includes a section about CPU profile too.

So, you need to record a cpu profile and look into it.

[image: BottomUp view]

Also you can use FlameChart view on it.

[image: FlameChart view]

You can click on an item in BottomUp or TopDown or even a FlameChart bar and see the function body in the Sources panel.

[image: minified version]

If you sources are minified, as in the screenshot, then you can press a button in the status bar of Sources panel. It looks like two curly braces {}. Then DevTools will format the sources.

[image: PrettyPrinted version]

and that action will affect all the links to the source file in all other places like Timeline, CPUProfile etc. As example in the first snapshot you saw a function O.Pk  that was at line 778 of minified version of the script. After pretty printing the source file the link to the function was changed automatically. Now it is pointing to the line 15871.

[image: changed links]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is the "Timeline" tab.  Seems to work in regular chrome.  I set the tab to record just before I triggered the action that caused the hang, once the hang stopped (took about 20 seconds), I stopped recording and used the left and right selectors to zoom in on the master timeline (at the top) where I saw an longer execution period (at the top) with "Events" selected.

[image: Timeline tab after capture]

From there I just expanded the dropdown and I got what I was looking for.  (I blurred out the js filenames to avoid singling out the library) but I'm including a screenshot.

Comment: If you had taken a CPU profile, you'd have got this in a much more readable form :)